# Verbstellung im Nebensatz mit "weil"

Tags: standard-german

Ich hoffe, dass ich nicht der Einzige bin, dem der Zerfall des deutschen Nebensatzes auffällt. Anstatt zu sagen: "Ich ging zum Arzt, weil ich krank war." sagen 95% der Leute mittlerweile: " Ich ging zum Arzt, weil ich war krank." Der Nebensatz nach dem Komma wird also ohne Umstellung einfach an den ersten Satzteil angehängt.

Bitte achtet mal drauf.

Ich bin der Meinung, dass dies vom Englischen her beeinflusst und mehr oder weniger verursacht wird: "I went to the doctor, because I was sick".

Am schlimmsten finde ich, dass dieses Phänomen auch in den Medien durchgängig auftritt. Angefangen bei ARD und ZDF bis hin zu Privatsendern und Radio.

Wie seht ihr das?

Oder bin ich der Einzige dem die Ohren dabei wehtun?

Comment: Tut mir leid, aber diese Frage ist viel zu meinungsbasiert für diese Seite. Siehe auch [hier](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Wenn du mal genau analysierst, was passiert, dann wirst du feststellen, dass der Verbzweit-Weil-Satz eine andere Funktion und Nuancierung hat als die reguläre Version. Wenn ich jemanden frage "Warum hast du meine Pizza gegessen?", dann ist die antwort nicht "Weil ich hatte Hunger." ... alle sagen es richtig. Die Deutsch Sprache wird also tatsächlich reicher und nicht ärmer. Zudem gibt es schon "denn" das dem "weil" semantisch sehr ähnlich ist. Wir brauchen also Englisch hier nicht. Und niemand würde einen dass-Satz mit Verbzweitstellung sagen, obschon das in Englisch eben genauso gemacht wird

Comment: Mit *"... , weil krank ich waren"* gibt es mindestens noch eine dritte Form (unter den Star Wars-Fans). Aber das nur am Rande ;)

Comment: Wieso ist die Frage meinungsbasiert? Entweder der Satztypus kommt aus dem Englischen oder nicht. Und entweder das kann man inzw. so sagen oder nicht. Dass man die richtige Antwort nicht weiß und gerne seine Meinung abgäbe macht die Frage nicht unmöglich.

Comment: Eine Meinung darf man schon haben, aber im vorliegendenden Fall gibt es hier schon eine Frage zum Thema. Jetzt muss nur noch der Titel besser werden ;)

Comment: Nein, da bist Du nicht der Einzige, denn *weil* leitet einen untergeordneten Nebensatz ein, dessen Verb am Ende steht. *Denn* leitet einen nebengeordneten Hauptsatz ein, dessen Form einfach einem normalen Hauptsatz gleicht. *Weil* mit einem Hauptsatz zu verwenden ist also nicht richtig - nur weil viele es machen, wird es nicht richtiger.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, grundsätzlich ist es natürlich in der Grammatik schon so, dass etwas richtig wird, wenn es genug Leute tun.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Die Diskussion habe ich oft genug. Der Meinung bin ich einfach nicht. Grammatik ist dazu da, sich an sie zu halten, sonst brauche ich ja einfach überhaupt gar keine Regeln.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - Richtig aber auch falsch :-P Die normative Kraft des Faktischen wischt alte Regeln des öfteren weg. Es kommt eben darauf an ob eine kritische Masse erreicht wird oder nicht. Völlig egal ob du der Meinung bist oder nicht. Mir persönlich gefällt das allerdings auch nicht.

Comment: @schlingel Das mag sein, und dem verschließe ich mich ja auch nicht - solange dann eine normative Kraft hergeht und die Regeln entsprechend anpasst. Und solange das nicht geschieht, kann ich mit Fug und Recht basierend auf den geltenden Regeln sagen: Wenn jemand *weil* mit einem Hauptsatz verwendet, dann ist das falsch. Basta. Wenn jemand die Regeln entsprechend ändert, dann wird es eventuell richtig.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, ok, dann ändere ich jetzt hiermit die Regel :)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Aha, bist Du denn zur Normierung der deutschen Sprache befugt? :-D

Comment: @userunknown: Diese Frage ist praktisch ein Musterbeispiel für: »there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”«, und: »your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”«.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, ich bin mir nicht sicher, wer ist befugt?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Mit der Frage kannst Du Dich getrost an das Institut für Deutsche Sprache wenden. Siehe zu dieser Frage auch hier: http://pub.ids-mannheim.de/laufend/jahrbuch/jb2008.html

Comment: @Carsten Schultz: Es gibt keine offizielle Instanz für die deutsche Grammatik – außer vielleicht die Sprecherschaft.